# Error while importing shapefile into Oracle

Tags: shapefile, geotools, oracle-spatial, sdo-geometry

I am trying to import shapefile into Oracle db using GeoTools, but when I am trying to create a new schema, it will giving me following error.

> Aug 01, 2021 8:24:13 PM org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore getMapping
> WARNING: No mapping for org.locationtech.jts.geom.MultiPolygon
> Aug 01, 2021 8:24:13 PM org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore getSQLTypeNames
> WARNING: Fetching fields from Database
> ***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/factory/Hints***

I am using following jars for this.

```
gt-jdbc-oracle-2.6.1
ojdbc8-12.2.0.1
```

Not able to found gt-epsg-oracle jar not sure if this is happening because of this jar.

Below is the code which I am using:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.geotools.data.DataStore;
import org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.DefaultTransaction;
import org.geotools.data.Transaction;
import org.geotools.data.collection.ListFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureStore;
import org.geotools.feature.FeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStoreFactory;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
import org.opengis.filter.identity.FeatureId;

public class WriteToDatabase {
    private static DataStore dataStore;

    public WriteToDatabase(Map<String, Object> params) throws IOException {

        dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
        if(dataStore != null && dataStore.getTypeNames() != null)
            System.out.println("Oracle connected");
    }

    public boolean isReady() {
        return dataStore != null;
    }

    public boolean writeFeatures(FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> features) {

        if (dataStore == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Datastore can not be null when writing");
        }
        SimpleFeatureType schema = features.getSchema();

        try {

            /*
             * Write the features
             */
            Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");

            String[] typeNames = dataStore.getTypeNames();
            // first check if we need to create table
            boolean exists = false;
            String schemaName = schema.getName().getLocalPart();
            for (String name : typeNames) {

                if (schemaName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    exists = true;
                }
            }
            if (!exists) {
                **dataStore.createSchema(schema);**
            }
            // we should probably check the schema matches the existing table.
            // but we don't
            SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource(schema.getName().getLocalPart());
            if (featureSource instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
                SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;

                featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
                try {
                    List<FeatureId> ids = featureStore.addFeatures(features);
                    transaction.commit();
                } catch (Exception problem) {
                    problem.printStackTrace();
                    transaction.rollback();
                } finally {
                    transaction.close();
                }
                dataStore.dispose();
                return true;
            } else {
                dataStore.dispose();
                System.err.println("Database not writable");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        File file;
        String path = "D:\\shppoc.shp";
        ShapefileDataStore shp = new ShapefileDataStore(new File(path).toURL());

        shp.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.USER.key, "GEO_LOAD");
        params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.PASSWD.key, "test");
        params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.HOST.key, "test");
        params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.PORT.key, "1521");
        params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.DATABASE.key, "/test1");
        params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.DBTYPE.key, "oracle");
        // create some random features and write them out;
        List<SimpleFeature> feats = new ArrayList<SimpleFeature>();

        SimpleFeatureIterator fi = shp.getFeatureSource().getFeatures().features();
        SimpleFeatureType sourceSchema = shp.getSchema();

        while (fi.hasNext()) {
            SimpleFeature source = (SimpleFeature) fi.next();
            feats.add(source);
        }

        WriteToDatabase writer = new WriteToDatabase(params);
        System.out.println("oracle.getTypeNames()"+dataStore.getTypeNames());
        String typeName = shp.getTypeNames()[0].toUpperCase();

        System.out.println("shp.getTypeNames()[0]===="+shp.getTypeNames()[0]);

        FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> features = new ListFeatureCollection(sourceSchema, feats);
        writer.writeFeatures(features);
    }
}
```

Attached is the pom , Also 2 jar i am adding externally because of not able to found in maven repository

gt-jdbc-oracle-2.6.1
ojdbc8-12.2.0.1

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>tutorial</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>26-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tukaani/xz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tukaani</groupId>
            <artifactId>xz</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-epsg-extension</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-referencing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.geotools</groupId> <artifactId>gt-epsg-oracle</artifactId> 
            <version>20.4</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.locationtech</groupId> <artifactId>jts</artifactId> 
            <version>1.13</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- Provides support for PostGIS. Note the different groupId -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-jdbc-postgis</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6 -->

    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>OSGeo Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo-snapshot</id>
            <name>OSGeo Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: GeoTools is currently on version 25.x - so I would first make sure I was using a version written in the last decade and then edit your question to show the dependencies in your pom.xml and the version of Java you are using.

Comment: I am currently using the latest version of geotools i.e 26-SNAPSHOT. Updated the pom in question and I am using 2 external jar mentioned in the question too.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to mix in a old jar (`gt-jdbc-oracle-2.6.1`) with modern GeoTools (`26-SNAPSHOT` are you actively debugging the GeoTools code or just trying to make life hard for yourself?).

**THIS WILL NOT WORK**

There is a reason we use Maven to control dependencies in Java projects and it is to explicitly prevent this from happening. So change your `pom.xml` to handle **all** your dependencies including `gt-jdbc-oracle` as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jdbc/oracle.html).

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.geotools.jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>gt-jdbc-oracle</artifactId>
   <version>${geotools.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

I don't have an oracle database to hand so I can't test your code but using the right dependency should help.

Comment: Fixing the external jar version worked for me. Thanks Ian